# Multiply columns based on two columns conditions from different dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes as indicated below:

```
dfA = 
Country      City           Pop
US           Washington     1000
US           Texas          5000
CH           Geneva         500
CH           Zurich         500


dfB = 
Country      City           Density (pop/km2)
US           Washington     10
US           Texas          50
CH           Geneva         5
CH           Zurich         5
```

What I want is to compare the columns `Country` and `City` from both dataframes, and when these match such as:

`US Washington & US Washington` in both dataframes, it takes the `Pop` value and divides it by `Density`, as to get a new column `area` in `dfB` with the resulting division. **Example of first row results** `dfB['area km2'] = 100`

I have tried with `np.where()` but it is nit working. Any hints on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `merge` to combine the two dataframes and divide as usual:

```
dfMerge = dfA.merge(dfB, on=['Country', 'City'])
dfMerge['area'] = dfMerge['Pop'].div(dfMerge['Density (pop/km2)'])
print(dfMerge)
```

Output:

```
  Country        City   Pop  Density (pop/km2)   area
0      US  Washington  1000                 10  100.0
1      US       Texas  5000                 50  100.0
2      CH      Geneva   500                  5  100.0
3      CH      Zurich   500                  5  100.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using index matching and `div`

```
match_on = ['Country', 'City']
dfA = dfA.set_index(match_on)
dfA.assign(ratio=dfA.Pop.div(df.set_index(['Country', 'City'])['Density (pop/km2)']))
```

---

```
Country  City      
US       Washington    100.0
         Texas         100.0
CH       Geneva        100.0
         Zurich        100.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Cool! So, for your two points. First, you can always `dropna` for the rows you won't use. By default, index matching performs a right-merge-like operation, so it makes sense some `NaN`s might pop up. Second, no problem. You can store and use `assign` - check edit

Comment: That's a different issue.. likely you have duplicate indexes.. Can you update your [mcve] for us to reproduce your (new) problem?

Comment: Nice! Then, pick the answer from those two that helped you most and accept it for future referrals ;}

Answer (score 0):

you can also use merge like below

```py
dfB["Area"] = dfB.merge(dfA, on=["Country", "City"], how="left")["Pop"] / dfB["Density (pop/km2)"]
dfB
```